# Why use a heap in Djkstra Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I wrote a pseudocode for Djkstra's Algorithm to finds shortest path from source vertex to all other nodes.
I believe that the code does not require a min-heap at all.
The code shared does not use a heap at all.

Could someone please let me know if I am doing something wrong here ?
The time complexity of my solution is O(V+E).

Please let me know if this works and can we eliminate heap from djkstra.

Thanks in advance

I have verified it on a piece of paper but in case I missed test cases.

Pseudo-code : --

```
q.add(src);

while (q is not empty) {
    int u = q.poll();

    if (visited[u] == true) {
        continue; //Node u has already served as a start vertex
    }

    for (Pair v: graph.getAdjacentsList()) {

        if (dist[u] + Pair.getweight() < dist[v]) {
            dist[v] = dist[u] + Pair.getweight();
            q.add(v.getDestinationVertex());
        }
        visited[u] = true; //Since we processed all children of u, mark it visited
    }
```

EDIT 1: For every neighbor, update their distances with min(already registered distance, dist(parent) + weight(parent,child))

Comment: Why is this tagged java _and_ c++? Which is it?

Comment: It's just  a pseudo code. Removed tags

Comment: Why `q` have `push` and `add`, are these different?

Comment: I think the reason why you need a min-Heap is that you want to "Pick a vertex u which is not there in `visited` and has minimum distance value.". From your code, the variable `q` should be the min-Heap

Comment: Dijkstra is a greedy algorithm that always process the next closest point first. you need some kind of data structure to pick the min node in a list. A `heap` is a convenient and efficient way to do it.

Comment: @Andyk. From what you are saying, Pick the parent with shortest path and append path with the current node. As per code, we append to every parent and check if path is minumum

Answer (score 3):

Assume the following graph and let's assume you're not using some kind of min-heap:

[image]

Let's say, a is our starting node. Youn have the reachable neighbors b and c. Because you do not use some kind of min-heap, you first visit b. Now there's the neighbor d, with cost of 1 from b (total cost of 4, which will be set for d). You mark b as visited.

Now you visit c with reachable neighbor b. Because total cost of 2 is lower than 3, you set the cost for b to 2, c has cost of 1. You mark c as visited.

Now you get to d, which does not have any neighbors, so set it to visited.

All your determined costs:

```
a -> c = 1,
a -> c -> b = 2,
a -> b -> d = 4,
```

but the shortest path to d is 3 via c. So in this case, the algorithm didn't find the shortest, but any path, which is not the intention of Dijkstra's algorighm. Using some kind of min-heap, you would have found the shortest path, because you would have visited c before b.